# How do I show multiple line from dynamic data using javascript in highchart

Tags: javascript, jsf, highcharts

I have a chart that is getting user input selection from a drop down list in jsf and generate chart based on the item selection. It is working perfectly. But If I want to select multiple items at a time and want to show multiple lines at a time, how is that possible? I know I have to use another jsf component instead of dropdown list. But I am not getting how can I pass multiple data series at the same time to highcharts. The sample code I used to generate chart based one single item selection is as following:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy',
        spacingRight: 20

    },

     title: {
        text: ''
    }, 

    xAxis: {
     startOnTick:true,
     showFirstLabel: true,
     endOnTick : true,
     showLastLabel:true,
     categories: dateAndTimeArray,
     tickInterval: 20,
     labels:{
     rotation:0.1,
     align: 'left',
     step: 12,   
     enabled: true

    },

    style: {
          fontSize: '8px'
       }
        }, 
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Measurement value'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        xDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
        shared: true
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            fillColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
                stops: [
                    [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                ]
            },
            lineWidth: 1,
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            shadow: false,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            },
          //  threshold: null
        }
    },

      series: [{
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Value',
        /* pointInterval: 0.75 * 3600 * 1000,
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2013, 1, 1),  */  
        data: chartData,
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }

    }]   

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not include your code for updating the chart with the data selected. So, this is just a general answer. The highchart [`series`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series) object can contain multiple elements:

```
series: [{series 1}, {series 2}]
```

You could get the list of the selected items in your ddl and then iterate over your data sets to find matches and use that to [`addSeries`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries).